# How to use compound statements or block

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use compound statements as the following:

```
namespace A
{
    namespace B
    {
        { //compound statement started here
            void foo()
            {
                printf("%d\n",i);
            }
            int i=5;
        } //ended here
    }
}

int main(){ }
```

But I've a compile-time error:

```
test.cpp:7:3: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token
test.cpp:19:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
test.cpp:19:1: error: expected ‘}’ at end of input
```

But I'm expected that it's ok. It is because compound statement defined as:

```
compound-statement:
   { statement-seq_opt }
```

at 6.3/1.

Answer (score 2):

Compound statements are only allowed within a function or method.

It's a special case of a statement and part of a function body 'fct-body' inside the grammar if I remember well.

Comment: Where is it specified in the standard? Please give me a reference.

Comment: @St.Antario If you could look up a reference, you can look up the grammar for namespaces, yourself. Start at the index of grammar productions and click "namespace-body."

Answer (score 1):

There are no statements directly inside namespaces, never mind compound statements.

You can only have declarations there. You can declare a function, which contains statements, or use declarations with initializers, which may execute actions as statements do.

In your example, the "statements" inside the compound-statement are declarations, so it's not clear what difference you want the extra braces to make.

Note, function definitions like the example `foo` are not valid declaration-statements.

Comment: Declarations are statements in C++. ITYM non-declaration statements.

Comment: @MattMcNabb A declaration in the context of a statement is a statement. Other declarations are not. Although, I suppose it depends how constructively you want to interpret the BNF.